# Colour Scheme for an iOS App - UIView and UIAppearance - Setting the Background Colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been researching how to create colour schemes for iOS apps.

Having started with a storyboard and manually setting the background colour for each component, I quickly realised that, while for toy apps, it was fine, for anything a bit more complicated, it would be both tedious and time consuming - particularly if you wanted to change all the colours again in the future.

This lead to me finding the UIAppearance protocol and I thought, as a starting point, how about just doing something like this:

```
[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

I was experimenting with Xcode 6 and using the Master-Detail App Template (Objective-C).  The result was not what I expected; I expected the app to look the same as it had before, but with an orange background.  What I actually got was the whole app showing as a single fullscreen rectangle of orange with no way to view the actual elements of the UI.  It effectively looks like both foreground and background colours were set to orange with no distinction (I would post the image of what I see, but I have insufficient reputation to do so at the moment).  I did also try using setTintColor, but the only UI elements this seemed to affect were the UITableView's 'Edit' and add '+' buttons whose text was set to Orange.

I'm able to get essentially the 'expected' result by setting the following (DetailViewUIAppearanceTest in the below snippet is an unmodified subclass of UIView which I set to be used for the detail view):

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[[DetailViewUIAppearanceTest appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[[UILabel appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

I know that's not a lot more code and it allows for finer grained control of appearance (just having solid orange may not be the best look after all!), but it leaves things that I don't understand, and if I don't understand then there may be unforseen pitfalls, so my questions on this are:

1. Why doesn't simply setting UIView's background colour actually set the background colour for all views (rather than making foreground and background one and the same)?
2. For the UINavigationBar, setBackgroundColor: seemed to have no effect, only setBarTintColor: had the expected result.  This behaviour doesn't seem to be consistent; does anyone know why this is so?
3. Bonus Question: Is there any-way to set class-wide, the background colour of a selected UITableViewCell?  The only method I've come across for this is the instance property 'selectedBackgroundView', one option would be to subclass this and set a given colour in the designated initialiser, but is there a better way?

As you can probably tell from the question, I'm new to iOS development; my background is server-side C++, and I'm working with Objective-C because it's a little closer to my comfort zone, and also Swift seems to be a moving target at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also relatively new to objective-c development but let me try to help you out here.

```
[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

This was causing the whole screen to turn orange because you are telling every view on the screen to set its background color to orange. Everything on the screen is a subclass of `UIView` - so that means `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` etc. That's why you'll need to be more fine-grained in your calling of `setBackgroundColor` and other related methods.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

As for the `UINavigationBar`, that is the way it is designed. As per the docs: `barTintColor` is the `tint color to apply to the navigation bar background.` Setting the `backgroundColor` directly will not have an effect. It is the way the element is designed. Perhaps someone else can give a more detailed reasoning why.

Also to change globally `UITableViewCell` the easiest way I've found is to subclass, and override the `setHighlighted` `setSelected` and `selectedBackgroundView` as you see fit.

If you want to override the highlighting color as well as the selected color (and support animation), what I have done before is:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    NSTimeInterval duration = animated ? .25f : 0.f;

    if (highlighted)
    {
        [self animateBackgroundTo:[UIColor orangeColor] duration:duration];
     }
    else
    {
        [self animateBackgroundTo:[UIColor whiteColor] duration:duration];
    }
}

- (void)animateBackgroundTo:(UIColor *)backgroundColor duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        } completion:nil];
}
```

If you do not want to subclass `UITableViewCell`, and just want to change its `backgroundColor`, you can use `UIAppearance` as such, which will change the `backgroundColor` for the `contentView` subview of the `UITableViewCell`s:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

You can use this call to change any element globally. It gives you further fine-grained control of which elements to change. For example

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolbar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

will change the tintColor of bar button items only when contained in `UIToolBar`s.

or

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolbar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.f]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

will change the font for bar button items when contained in `UIToolBar`s.

Edit:
The `tintColor` property is extremely handy when themeing your app. You can use it in any view (it is passed down through the view hierarchy from your `UIViewController`'s main view) to set color of any elements.

For example, say you have a custom `UITableViewCell` that you want to have one of the labels be whatever tint color your app is using. So you override `tintColorDidChange` like so:

```
- (void)tintColorDidChange
{
    [self.label setTextColor:self.tintColor];
}
```

Then when you set in your `UIViewController`

```
self.view.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Magically, your cells will now have orange labels! (You'll need to redraw the cells by calling `reloadData` or similar)

As to the `setTintColor` only changing the `UIBarButtonItem`s. Changing the `tintColor` on the `UINavigationBar` changes the `tintColor` of all subviews as well, meaning in this case the `tintColor` on the `UINavigationBarItem`s is changed, which they use as their title `textColor`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kris, your answer helped me to solve some of the other practical issues I was having with colouring too.  The part you pointed out about being able to colour based on hierarchy was particularly useful as when I was working on an embedded UITableView and couldn't get the colour right all the way through.

One thing I'm not so sure about still is the UIView setting of the background colour.   I get that pretty much everything inherits from UIView and you're setting the background colour for all, but I don't see why that eclipses any 'foreground' colours that were previously visible.

Comment: That's great! Glad to help. As for the `UIView` issue. If I am reading correctly I think what is happening is again all the views are setting the `backgroundColor` to orange. To clarify, I mean that even `UILabel`s inherit from `UIView` - so even their `backgroundColor` will be changed to orange. However, if you are saying that even the `textColor` is being changed to orange, that is odd. I am not sure why that would be the case. Maybe if you detail what you mean by foreground colors I can help some more.

Comment: The appearance is as if things like `textColor` have been set to orange too, so even labels that are present on the canvas are invisible because they are the same colour as the background (and in the storyboard the `textColor` is black).  That may not actually be what's happening, it just appears to be what's happening.  Perhaps there is a fullscreen view in the foreground of the default app template that would normally be transparent - if that's so I could certainly understand that setting its background to solid orange would eclipse everything else in the app

Comment: I tried running through Xcode 6's 3d view debugger and in there (having set `UIView`'s `backgroundColor` globally), in the debugger, the UI looked exactly as it should and there was no sign of an obscuring window in front, while on the simulator I just got the solid orange block with no sign of any label text.

Comment: Well that is certainly odd! Yeah I don't know enough honestly to answer that. Perhaps someone else will weigh in. Would be interesting to know why. Have you tried on device?

Comment: Delayed response, sorry; I did try on device after your message and it shows the same as the simulator.  It's more of academic interest now since we do have a working technique to get the desired appearance.  Having said that, if anyone does know why there is the discrepancy between the view debugger and device/simulator, it would still be very interesting to know.